# How select an item in a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

Im programming a tiny music player for school project. And our teacher tell us we have to use linked list.

But i have this crash in my program without warnings, my function Afficher_Liste is working fine (its a function to view my linked list)

My structure which define a music

```
typedef struct Piste{
    char *pTitle;
    char *pArtist;
    char *pPath;
    struct Piste *pNext;
    struct Piste *pPrev;
}Piste;
```

My function :

```
void Play_Music(Piste **pHead){

    int choice;
    int ctr = 1;
    char * path_music;

    path_music= (char*)malloc(200 * sizeof(char));

    View_List(&ppDL);

    Piste *pCur = *pHead;


    printf("What music you want to play ?");
    scanf("%d",&choice);

    while(choix!=cptr){
        pCur = pCur->pNext;
        ctr++;
        if(choice==cptr){
            path_music= pCur->pPath;
        }
    }
    printf("your choice is %s",path_music);
    scanf("%d",choice);
}
```

Edit : the call of the function

```c
void User_Mode(){

    int choice;
    char *search= NULL;

    while(choice!= 4)
    {
        system("cls");

        printf("---------- User Menu----------\n\n");
        printf("1 - Search\n");
        printf("2 - Play a music\n");
        printf("3 - Back to menu\n");
        printf("your choice?\n");
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        switch(choice){

        case 1:
            fflush(stdin);
            search = (char*)malloc(200 * sizeof(char));
            printf( "what do you want to listen  ? : \n" );
            scanf( "%[^\n]", seach);
            fgetc( stdin );
            if(search!=NULL){
                search_music(search,&ppDL);
            }

            break;
        case 2:
            play_music();
            break;
        case 3:
            main_menu();
            break;
        default:
            system("cls");
            printf("your choice isnt good\n\n");
            user_mode();
        }
    }
}
```

Edit2 : tried to translate my code

Comment: Please include the call to Lecture_Musique.

Comment: I have no idea what is happening in this code as I do not read french fluently, but the last line of code should be `("%d", &choix)` rather than `scanf("%d",choix);`, otherwise it is likely reading that input into illegal memory.

Comment: @Dmitry it's a "useless" scanf, im using this to debug my function

Comment: You're not passing anything into the function in the code that you posted.  From what I can see, I have a few notes.  1) Since you are not editing pHead, you don't have to pass a pointer-to-a-pointer, so Lecture_Musique(Piste *pHead) is sufficient. 2) You're calling View_List(&ppDL), but ppDL is not a function parameter, so the fact that View_List(&ppDL) is working is not relevant to the Play_Music not working. What is the type of ppDL?

Comment: @Topher, i put this in global ```Piste *ppDL=NULL;```

Comment: The code as presented would not compile because you are not passing anything into "play_music" (in "case 2").  What are you passing into "play_music"?

Comment: The code compiled but it crashed. Im passing a pointer which is the first element of my list @Topher

Comment: Change "View_List(&ppDL)" to "View_List(pHead)" and see if your list still prints.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245502/discussion-between-topher-and-julien1h).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your case statement to

```
case 2:
        play_music( &ppDL );
        break;
```